# How to select and scale same time

Tags: selection-tools, scale

help how I can make this scale on selection at the same time

[image: help how I can make this scale on selection at the same time]

Comment: do you mean like this? https://youtu.be/kyB7eoT8ky8

Comment: oh shoot comments here are so small didn't notice no I didn't extrude

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/DjMXmp1 i mean this do this

Answer (score 1):

Selecting just the outer edges doesn't work in this case, this is how I would do it:

1. In *Edit Mode* use *Face Select*, select all the inner faces of those grooves.
2. Make sure you have set the *Transform Pivot Point* set to *Individual Origins*.
3. Hit <kbd>S</kbd> and then <kbd>Z</kbd> to scale them on the Z axis as far as you want the outer edges to be.
4. Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad Minus</kbd> to reduce the selection of the inner faces.
5. Scale them back again on the Z axis with <kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm never thought actually that way thanks

Comment: You're welcome... you might consider upvoting or accepting this answer.